# Вывод innerHTML в цикле в зависимости от количества элементов в массиве

Tags: javascript, while

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: нужно в тег `<ul>` вставить теги `li` в количестве равном количеству элементов в массиве.

```
var player = ["10","9"]; //это как пример

while (i <= player.length){
    cardsPlayer.innerHTML += '<li data-value=' + '"' + player[i] + playerSymbol[i] + '"' + '><p><span></span>'+ playerSymbol[i] + '</p></li>';
    i++;
}
```

Но вместо 2 элементов выводится 3,2 нормально, а третий `Undefined`.
Где я допустил ошибку? всё же верно, массив строго задан.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в ошибочном использовании `<=` вместо `<` так как индексация массива начинается с 0.

В данном случае лучше воспользоваться функциями для работы с массивами. Тут подойдет функция `map`

```
cardsPlayer.innerHTML += player.map((p,i)=>`<li data-value="${p}${playerSymbol[i]}"><p><span></span>${playerSymbol[i]}</p></li>`).join();
```