# Почему undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
var alphabet =['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K',
               'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 
               'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
for(var i = 0; i<= alphabet.length; i++) {
    alphabet[i] = alphabet[i].toLowerCase();
}
```

Ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined.

Почему *alphabet[i]* - *undefined*?

Comment: потому что опечатка и должно быть `<` вместо `<=`

Comment: счет начинается с нуля вместо i<= alphabet.length попробуй   i< alphabet.length

Comment: Спасибо, ребята!

Comment: вот еще такой же вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/550542/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-innerhtml-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5/550545#550545

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в цикле, `i <= alphabet.length` тут `i`будет на 1 больше чем сам массив, что и приводит тому что элемент массива не определен, учитывая то что индексация массива начинается с 0.

```
for(var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
  alphabet[i] = alphabet[i].toLowerCase();
}
```

Если так написать то все поправиться.

Comment: не определен не массив, в элемент массива по указанному индексу

Comment: @Grundy Да я подправил :))